# Event for open and close date picker

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I am using https://easepick.com date range picker.

I am looking for the event in which event can be fire on opening of the date range picker and also fire when close the range picker.

If I can find the event for both then I want to resize the Iframe height on opening of range picker and on close I want to reset my iframe size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Easypick](https://easepick.com/) provides the following 5 [events](https://easepick.com/packages/core.html#events):

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| render |  |
| view |  |
| preselect | Event is called on select days (before submit selection). When `autoApply` option is `false`. |
| select | Event is called when selection is submitted. |
| clear |  |

---

You can use the `select` event to trigger the `CLOSE` action, this will trigger if the user selects a date.

Unfortunately there is no `OPEN` event, so your best option is to add a native `click` event on the DOM `<input>`.

```js
document.querySelector('#datepicker').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Open');
});

const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    css: [
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css',
    ],
    setup(picker) {
        picker.on('select', (e) => {
            console.log('Close');
        });
    },
});
```

```html
<input id="datepicker"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.umd.min.js"></script>
```